# Access Database not accepting inserts with certain value using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, jet

Im working in Access 2010 with a backend JET Database, inserting values into that database.

This doesn't insert into the database (no error msg returned)

```
insert into [PROJECT RESOURCE UPDATE HISTORY] ([Current Date], [Project Auto No Ref], 
    [Resource ID Ref], [Allocation Notes], [Allocation Role],[Usage Percentage - Oct], 
    [Usage Percentage - Nov], [Usage Percentage - Dec], [Usage Percentage - Jan],
    [Usage Percentage - Feb], [Usage Percentage - Mar], [Usage Percentage - Apr], 
    [Usage Percentage - May],[Usage Percentage - Jun], [Usage Percentage - Jul], 
    [Usage Percentage - Aug], [Usage Percentage - Sep] ) values (#2/13/2017 11:01:41 AM#,
    540,11,'','Project Manager',0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

But this does

```
insert into [PROJECT RESOURCE UPDATE HISTORY] ([Current Date], [Project Auto No Ref], 
    [Resource ID Ref], [Allocation Notes], [Allocation Role],[Usage Percentage - Oct], 
    [Usage Percentage - Nov], [Usage Percentage - Dec], [Usage Percentage - Jan],
    [Usage Percentage - Feb], [Usage Percentage - Mar], [Usage Percentage - Apr], 
    [Usage Percentage - May],[Usage Percentage - Jun], [Usage Percentage - Jul],
    [Usage Percentage - Aug], [Usage Percentage - Sep] ) values (#2/13/2017 11:04:38 AM#,
    540,821,'','DevOps',0,0.13,0.13,0.13,0.13,0.13,0.13,0,0,0,0,0)
```

and here is a snippet of code that does the actual inserting

```
sqlStatement2 = "insert into [PROJECT RESOURCE UPDATE HISTORY] (" & _
    "[Current Date], [Project Auto No Ref], [Resource ID Ref], [Allocation Notes], [Allocation Role]," & _
    "[Usage Percentage - Oct], [Usage Percentage - Nov], [Usage Percentage - Dec], [Usage Percentage - Jan]," & _
    "[Usage Percentage - Feb], [Usage Percentage - Mar], [Usage Percentage - Apr], [Usage Percentage - May]," & _
    "[Usage Percentage - Jun], [Usage Percentage - Jul], [Usage Percentage - Aug], [Usage Percentage - Sep] " & _
    ") values (" & _
    "#" & Now() & "#," & _
    rst![Current Project Ref No] & "," & rst![Current Resource Person ID] & ",'" & rst![Current Allocation Notes] & _
    "','" & rst![Current Allocation Role] & "'," & CDbl(oct) & "," & CDbl(nov) & "," & CDbl(dec) & _
    "," & CDbl(jan) & "," & CDbl(feb) & "," & CDbl(mar) & "," & CDbl(apr) & _
    "," & CDbl(may) & "," & CDbl(jun) & "," & CDbl(jul) & "," & CDbl(aug) & _
    "," & CDbl(sep) & ");"
    MsgBox (sqlStatement2)
    CurrentDb.Execute (sqlStatement2)
    rst.MoveNext
```

I believe that the issue surrounds inserting 1 into the database in the first example. The database doesn't report back an error and the row doesn't appear. If change the value from 1 to 0.99, it insert fine and shows up in the database. 
Things that I have tried and observations:

1. I have also tried to manually converting 1 into a double using the CDbl() function before I do the insert statement in my vba code.
2. If I break the code after the first insert with value 1, the row id skips to the next value like the row was inserted

Where else can I look?

Comment: I bet if you hard coded 1.0 as a value it would work. What are your regional settings, I wonder if it interpreting the 1,1,1 as a number  ?

Comment: *"The database doesn't report back an error"* - Try using `CurrentDb.Execute sqlStatement2, dbFailOnError` and see if it behaves differently.

Comment: @gordThompson With the dbFailOnError, I found that it was a validation error in the table itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The database doesn't report back an error and the row doesn't appear.

That's because the default behaviour of the `.Execute` method is such that

```vbs
CurrentDb.Execute (sqlStatement2)  ' with no second argument
```

will avoid throwing an error if the query encounters difficulties. You should be using

```vbs
CurrentDb.Execute sqlStatement2, dbFailOnError
```

so `.Execute` can tell you why the INSERT was unsuccessful.